# Can you explain the purpose of array+5 in this program?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

I understand how most of it works, except for the second line in the `main` function: `int* end = array+5;`. How does that line work?

```
#inlcude <iostream>
int main()
{
    int array[] = {10, 20, 29, 200, 2};

    int* end = array+5;
    for(int* it = array; it != end; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It is supposed to just print every element in the list.

Comment: Syntax  `array+5` is equals to `&array[5]`. That line declares a pointer to the address of 5th memory block in the array (which is not valid block in this case). I recommend to not use that syntax.

Answer (score 9):

```
it != end;
```

means that it reached the position [5], which is one after the last (4).

```
int* end = array + 5;
```

simply creates a variable pointing to that [5] position.

It works, but a much more clean and safe version is:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
    std::cout << it[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, you can replace the hardcoded 5 with `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)`, or, even better, use a std::array.

```
std::array arr<int,5> = {10, 20, 29, 200, 2};
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++)
{
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
 std::array arr<int,5> = {10, 20, 29, 200, 2};
 for(auto& it : arr)
 {
    std::cout << it << std::endl;
 }
```

The latter forms are as fast as the plain raw array, but a lot safer.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question of what  "int* end = array+5;" actually does.

Comment: The latter two forms can also be used on c-style array (`std::size(arr)` in the first case)

Comment: I really like the answer! The alternatives are indeed much better. Please also note that the ranges based for also works with the C-style array, as long as it ain't passed as an argument

Answer (score 7):

The variable `array` is like a pointer to the beginning of the memory which contains the data.

The length of `array` is `5`, so adding 5 to the beginning gives the position of one past the end.

```
start --|  
       10, 20, 29, 200, 2, (out of array)
        |--- +5 -----------^
```

The condition `it != end` checks if the loop is not out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

For any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`. Together with array decay (which means that e.g. `array` is equal to `&array[0]`) means that `array + 5` will be equal to `&array[5]`.

So your loop is iterating from `&array[0]` (which is what `array` is equal to) to one `&array[4]` (inclusive). The loop is iterating over all five elements of `array`, making `it` point to every element or the array in turn.

Answer (score 2):

To understand `int* end = array+5;`, one should know how the memory has been laid out for `int array[] = {10, 20, 29, 200, 2}`. Have represented the same below for better understanding. Addresses are given in both decimal and hexadecimal for performing arithmetic operations easily.

```
               Address table 
          -----------------------------------------------------------
array ===>|   100   |   104   |   108   |   112   |   116  |   120  |  -----> DECIMAL
          |  0x100  |  0x104  |  0x108  |  0x10C  |  0x110 |  0x114 |  -----> HEXADECIMAL
          -----------------------------------------------------------
               |         |         |         |         |        
              10        20        29        200        2

'array' will be pointing to 0x100
```

The statement `int* end = array + 5;` is compiled to a code which is equivalent to `int* end = (array + (sizeof(int) * 5));`

So it gets evaluated as `int* end = (0x100 + (4 * 5)) = 0x114(decimal equivalent 120);` which is the address next to the last element. So `end` will be pointing to next to last element.

It is important to remember the value to be added or subtracted from the array's base address always depends on the datatype which is `int` in your case and the `sizeof(int)` is assumed to be `4 bytes`.

---

On a side note, datatype arr[index]; gets evaluated as `*(arr + (sizeof(datatype) * index))`.

Answer (score 0):

`array + 5` is equivalent to `&array[5]`.

Since `array` in your sample code is an array of five elements.

> ```
> int array[] = {10, 20, 29, 200, 2};
> ```

the initialisation

> ```
> int* end = array+5;
> ```

causes `end` to be a pointer to one past the end of the array, and the end condition in the loop

> ```
> for(int* it = array; it != end; ++it)
> {
>     std::cout << *it << std::endl;
> }
> ```

means the loop ends once `it` points past the end of the array (in your example, it points at `array[5]`).    This is perfectly fine in C++, since a pointer to one past the end of an array is allowed to be calculated or to be compared with other pointers to elements of that array.   However, dereferencing such a pointer (e.g. in your example, using it to access the value of `array[5]`) causes undefined behaviour..

In C++11 and later, the functions `std::begin()` and `std::end()` (from standard header `<iterator>`) if given an array argument, return the addresses of the first element and one-past-the-last element respectively.   So your code is functionally equivalent, for `array` having five elements, to;

```
int *end = std::end(array);
for(int *it = std::begin(array); it != end; ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

It is also equivalent to the more concise, and often preferred since it is less error prone;

```
for (const auto &element : array)    // const since the loop body doesn't change the array
{
    std::cout << element << std::endl;
}
```